# Linux use ".." to go one directory up while setting environ variables

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

```
$ls /usr/local
bin etc games include lib man sbin share src
```

I have an environment variable for instance

```
export temp=/usr/local/sbin
```

I want to set a different environment variable using `temp` by going one level up and set it to `bin`

I have tried `export temp2=$temp:/../bin`

```
echo $temp2
```

I see output

```
/usr/local/sbin:/../bin
```

expected output

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: `temp=/usr/local/sbin/../bin`? Why the `:` in the middle?

Comment: We could give you possible 1000 different reasons why this is not working, but to really help you out we would like you to tell use why you believe this should work. What is your reasoning. Only then we can help you and explain you in detail why the above does not work.

Comment: @SuryaTej: Assuming that /usr/local would be a symbolic link to, say, /foo/bar, would you then expect `/foo/bar/bin` or still `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Please describe the problem rather than just the solution you attempted. See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @KurtisRader the solution I attempted/mentioned in the question is my exact situation, except that in the actual problem the environment variables I am supposed to use are copyrighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash` substitution:

```
temp2="${temp/\/sbin//bin}"
# or else
# temp2="${temp%/sbin}/bin"
echo "$temp2"
```

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Or if you don't know last part of path then use this as suggested by @Lucas:

```
temp2=${temp%/*}/bin
```

Comment: In case we do not know the last component exactly we can match against anything like this: `temp2=${temp%/*}/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are surprised that it doesn't work; the stuff after the equals sign is just a string.

What you can do is use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
bash$ temp2=${temp%/sbin}/bin
```

(Unless you specifically require this variable to be made available to subprocesses, there is no need to `export` it.)

If you are lazy, you can just use ../bin:

```
bash$ temp2=$temp/../bin
```

but again, that's just a string which ultimately resolves to `/usr/local/bin` if you use it as a pathname.

Comment: the parameter expansion works, I wanted to see if .. just works like windows. Also `bash$ temp2=$temp/../bin` didn't work. double check that please and I will accept your answer

Comment: How do you mean "didn't work"? It assigns `/usr/local/sbin/../bin` to `temp2` which will resolve to `/usr/local/bin` if you e.g. `cd "$temp2"`

Comment: gotcha, i just tried printing the varibale and not cd. my bad